# Plotting a function as a function of another function in Mathematica

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica

I wasn't entirely sure what to search for, so if this question has been asked before, I apologize in advance:

I have two functions

R := Rref*mx(mx^(4/3) - C0)^(-1)

M := Mref*(mx + C1*mx^(-1)*((1 - C0*mx^(-4/3))^(-3) - 1))

where Rref, Mref, C0 and C1 are constants and mx is the variable. I need to plot R as a function of M. Surely there must be something available in Mathematica to do such a plot - I just can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is correct, in that what you have is a set of two ["parametric equations"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation). You would use the `ParametricPlot` command. However, the syntax of functions with parameters is sometimes tricky, so let me give you my best recommendation:

```
R[Rref_, C0_, C1_][mx_] = Rref*mx (mx^(4/3) - C0)^(-1);
M[Mref_, C0_, C1_][mx_] = Mref*(mx + C1*mx^(-1)*((1 - C0*mx^(-4/3))^(-3) - 1));
```

I like that notation better because you can do things like derivatives:

```
R[Rref,C0,C1]'[mx]

(* Output: -((4 mx^(4/3) Rref)/(3 (-C0 + mx^(4/3))^2)) + Rref/(-C0 + mx^(4/3)) *)
```

Then you just plot the functions parametrically:

```
ParametricPlot[
 {R[0.6, 0.3, 0.25][mx], M[0.2, 0.3, 0.25][mx]},
 {mx, -10, 10},
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}
]
```

You can box this up in a `Manipulate` command to play with the parameters:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  {R[Rref, C0, C1][mx], M[Mref, C0, C1][mx]},
  {mx, -mmax, mmax},
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}
 ],
 {Rref, 0, 1},
 {Mref, 0, 1},
 {C0, 0, 1},
 {C1, 0, 1},
 {mmax, 1, 10}
]
```

That should do it, I think.